# Azure DevOps Variable Groups Password not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm having userName and passWord field in my **`Azure DevOps Variable group,`** and I would like to pass the userName and passWord to my python script as a command line argument, I'm able to get the userName without any issue but passWord is not coming when I pass it from my pipeline script. I tried printing using echo - its printing empty - not evening printing masked value like this `'*****'`

**Please find my pipeline code below:**

```
trigger:
  - none

variables:
    - group: myVariableGrp

pool:
  name: myAgents

stages:
  - stage: Testing
    jobs:
      - job: Test
        displayName: Test script
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Test variable
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                echo "hello variables"
                echo $USER_NAME
                echo $MY_PASSWORD 

          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: Test Python script
            inputs:
              script: python test.py $USER_NAME $MY_PASSWORD
```

**test.py**

```
import sys

# total arguments
#n = len(sys.argv)
#print("Total arguments passed:", n)
print("UserName:", sys.argv[1])
print("Password:", sys.argv[2])
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print("Password:", sys.argv[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Test Python script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret variables are not automatically exposed as env variables. You have to explicitly map them: [Reference secret variables in variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#reference-secret-variables-in-variable-groups).
In this case, it would be:

```yaml
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Test variable
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              env:
                MAPPED_PASSWORD: $(MY_PASSWORD)
              script: |
                echo "hello variables"
                echo $USER_NAME
                echo $MAPPED_PASSWORD
```